# New line in pgfplots/tikz not displaying in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line-breaking, legend, matlab2tikz

I have a multiple-line legend entry to preserve the width of my figure. I can use 
`\newline` in Matlab and the legend entry is split between two lines. When I produce a `.tikz` of the figure however, I can't figure out how to get a new line... It appears there was a similar issue or the same issue [github of matlab2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz/issues/129#issuecomment-7933391) but when I use this syntax the same issue arises where Matlab shows the multi-line legend entry but LaTeX doesn't. Am I missing a package or writing the syntax wrong ?

LaTeX code generated by `matlab2tikz` to display the multiline legend (`\newline` works in matlab, tried `"\n"` and tried removing all of the `\text{}`'s which didn't help - the `\newline` command is just ignored by LaTeX):

`\addlegendentry{$\text{R}_{\text{Darcy,pwr}}\text{ = [1.26x10}^{\text{10}}\text{, 3.76x10}^{\text{9}}\text{] (1/m)**\newline** MAE=1.14x10}^{\text{-2}}\text{(g/min)}$};`

Unfortunately I can't post images because I don't have 10 repuation... sorry about the 
links:

**Matlab output:**

[image]

**LaTeX output:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: You can use `\parbox` for the this case.

Comment: try using `fig2texPS`  matlab script that does good job in converting figures to tex , also , Matlab outputs .eps(vector graphics and you can use figure without worry about quality)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated**

According to @Jake's comment, adding the key `[align=left]` will allow one to type multiple lines in the legend (I guess this is the same for entering multi-line texts in a TikZ node):

```
\addlegendentry[align=left]{
  $\text{R}_\text{Darcy,pwr}=[1.26 \times 10^{10},\; 3.76\times 10^9]$ \\
  $\text{(1/m)MAE}=1.14\times 10^{-2} \text{ (g/min)}$
}
```

A working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  legend style={at={(1.1,-0.1)},
  cells={anchor=west}, % left-align cell content
}]

\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addlegendentry{$\downarrow\Delta P$, 1$^{st}$ cycle}

\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\addlegendentry{DGM $\delta'_{\text{air}}=4.8\times 10^{-8}$ m-kPa}

\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,3)};
\addlegendentry[align=left]{
  $\text{R}_\text{Darcy,pwr}=[1.26 \times 10^{10},\; 3.76\times 10^9]$ \\
  $\text{(1/m)MAE}=1.14\times 10^{-2} \text{ (g/min)}$
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I apologize for not including a MWE but really appreciate you showing the figure. This answered my question plus some because the "\times" looks better than "x" thanks!