# How to increase the length of a legend box in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

If I have a legend using PGFPlots too long near the right margin of the document I can not see part of it. **How can I insert a line break inside the legend, or adjust the length?** (The legend is on the outside of the graph). For example:

```
\addlegendentry{$\text{IntegralNumérica1 }=\text{ ResuelveEDO}(x+y^2,\;0,\;0\;2\;0.1)}
```

[image: Legend Box]

Is there any way to do something like this?:

```
\addlegendentry{$\text{IntegralNumérica1 }=$ \\ $\text{ ResuelveEDO}(x+y^2,\;0,\;0\;2\;0.1)$}
```

I tried adding `legend style={line width=2.8pt}` in the `axis` environment but produces error.

Any help? Thanks!

**EDIT: MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{
  Cus/.style={
        axis equal image,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        view={0}{90},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[
        Cus,
        xmin=-4.1, xmax=4.1,
        ymin=-5.1, ymax=4.1,
        xtick={-4,-2,...,4}, ytick={-6,-4,...,4},
        samples=20,
        legend pos=outer north east
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,red] {x^2};
        \addlegendentry{$\text{BlablablablablablablablablablablaBlablablablablablablablablablablaBlablablablablablablablablablabla}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Legend Error]

**EDIT 2: I forgot to mention that I have more than one legend.**

Comment: please provide small, complete document with your `pgfplots` diagram, which show your problem.

Comment: You prevent line breaks by putting everything into a math environment. `\addlegendentry{$\text{IntegralNumérica1 }=$  $\text{ ResuelveEDO}(x+y^2,\;0,\;0\;2\;0.1)}$` should already do the line break.

Comment: @Zarko Added MWE.

Comment: Hello @marmot, I promised you that I would take you out of your hibernation state hahaha. Does not work `:(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my wrong comment. And sorry, I guided you in the wrong direction. Your question is quite likely a duplicate of those leading to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115483/121799) and [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280109/121799), which however seem not to be duplicates of another.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{
  Cus/.style={
        axis equal image,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        view={0}{90},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[
        Cus,
        xmin=-4.1, xmax=4.1,
        ymin=-5.1, ymax=4.1,
        xtick={-4,-2,...,4}, ytick={-6,-4,...,4},
        samples=20,
        legend pos=outer north east,
         legend style={cells={align=left,anchor=west}}
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,red] {x^2};
        \addlegendentry{Maecenas eu tortor\\ eu diam fringilla\\
         scelerisque sit\\ amet eget enim.\\
Nam vitae bibendum erat,\\ sit amet scelerisque\\ felis. Suspendisse placerat\\
vitae velit pharetra\\ lobortis et marmottae. }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add to that that I forgot to mention that I have more than one legend... So I am adding the parameters that are between `[...]` to each `addlegendentry`, and modifying both to fit them to my original document. Laborious work `:P`

Comment: @manooooh Sorry again, and please have a look at my revised answer.

Comment: Lol I search for a possible duplicate (here and Google) but I couldn't find anything. Thanks again, it works for me, and don't worry for the wrong comment

Comment: @manooooh So did I, and couldn't find the others at first either. Google picture search finally led me to the above links. Interestingly, both question happily coexisted till now without being marked as duplicates. The criteria for being a duplicate are not clear to me, see e.g. [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/too-rash-decision-about-duplicate).

Comment: I red that thread and the discussion, for me is fine to close a question for being a duplicate, like this one. If we don't have organization we are nothing! Idk why both questions are still open `O.o`